# How to assign shortcut keys in Gnome?

Tags: 11.04, shortcut-keys, gnome

My laptop has several buttons on the very left,

Calculator, Unknown, Web Browser, Unknown, Mail.

I know these work as the calculator, mail, and web browser buttons work,

I want to map the other two buttons, the first Unknown I wish to map to "open nautilus", the second one I wish to map to "open terminal" How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My assumption is that Unity 3D (with Compiz) is being used.  Ensure that Compiz Configuration Settings Manager (CCSM) has been installed => [compizconfig-settings-manager](http://packages.ubuntu.com/compizconfig-settings-manager) [image: Install compizconfig-settings-manager]

Once CCSM has been successfully installed, start the CCSM application.  Under the **General** category, select **Commands**

From here it is simply a matter of configuring the command and appropriate key-binding (see the above image).  As noted above, to start Nautilus the appropriate command is `nautilus`.  For Gnome-Terminal, the command is `gnome-terminal`.  I hope this helps.

Comment: The question is tagged with Gnome3, so I assume that's what he was going for.

Comment: I did not originally see that.  Sorry about any confusion I created.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that you're using Gnome3 as your question is tagged with Gnome3

1 Open Settings (SUPER, they type 'settings')

2 Keyboard

3 Shortcuts Tab

4 Custom Shortcuts

5 Hit the + button

For Nautilus the command is `nautilus`. There's actually a pre-made shortcut for terminal under the "Launchers" option on the left side, you just have to set it to the button you want.